# How to create clickable html elements like div-s on a picture in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, draw

I am pretty new to Laravel and I need to make a project using that framework. In that project I need to display an image in a loaded view and on that image I need to draw/display html elements like `div-s` for example. These elements need to be drawn using (x,y) coordinates taken from a database and also must be clickable.

The whole purpose of the project is so that people could click on elements that are drawn on the image and they could "reserve" a place for themselves. For example, imagine a company's representative reserving a spot on the exhibition floor at a conference.

How should I do it? I am a bit lost, but was thinking about using JavaScript. [Here is an example image with elements on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2r5w.png)

Comment: This question is far far to broad for Stackoverflow. There are numerous ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but none of them are straightforward enough to explain in an answer here. When you've got some code and have a specific problem or bug, come back and we'll help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir,I will try to do more research.When I will have some code and bump into a problem I will ask for help.

Comment: One last thing and I will not bother anyone again until I have a specific code related problem.Would you please share a link to a question or a problem which is somehow related to my wrongly asked question? Of course I will be searching as well for the answer.Thank you for your patience.